# How can I add column to the admin from other table, that isn't directly connected?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-admin

I have four tables connected together:

- `Meeting` (two foreign keys of `Person`)
- `Person` (many to many field to 'ConditionDictionary'
- `Condition` (foreign key of `Person` and `ConditionDictionary`)
- `ConditionDictionary`

my `Meeting` table has foreign key of `Person` and `Person` is connected many-to-many to `ConditionDictionary`, which goes through table `Condition` (because I had to add extra flags there).

I want to add one column from `ConditionDictionary` to meeting view, but I have no idea how can I do it.

When running in python shell, I achieve what I need

`Meeting.objects.filter(id=1).values('person_in_need__person_c__condition__issue')`

But, as mentioned above, I have no idea how to add the option to choose what it returns on the meeting class.

Here are the models (the important bits):

```
class ConditionDictionary(models.Model):

    issue = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    description = models.TextField()


class Condition(models.Model):

    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name = 'person_c', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    condition = models.ForeignKey(ConditionDictionary, related_name = 'condition_c', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Person(models.Model):

    issue = models.ManyToManyField(ConditionDictionary, through='Condition')


class Meeting(models.Model):

    person1 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='in_need', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    person2 = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='carer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

My idea is that with every meeting created, you could choose what issue is treated this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can show related table data using django's `__` (double underscore).

For example, I've got a `Profile` model which links to `User`. `User` also links to a `Passport` model.

You can see here in the `search_fields` that it's going to do a search on the ID of the `User` and also through the `User` table to the `Passport` table to search that by ID;

```
@admin.register(Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """ Model admin for Profile. """
    # List attributes.
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'user',
    )
    list_filter = (
        'series_entrant',
    )
    search_fields = (
        'user__id',
        'user__email',
        'user__first_name',
        'user__last_name',
        'user__passport__id'
    )
```

To display related data in the `fields` of an admin class you can make a callable and add it to the readonly fields. For example;

```py
@admin.register(AddOn)
class AddOnAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    AddOn model admin
    """
    list_display = (
        'id',
        'get_related',
        'enabled',
        'created',
    )
    readonly_fields = (
        'created',
        'modified',
        'get_related',
    )
    fields = (
        'enabled',
        'get_related',
        'name',
        'description',
        'created',
        'modified',
    )

    def get_related(self, obj):
        """
        Get some related data
        """
        return obj.realted_model.field
    get_related.short_description = _('Related')
```

Comment: So it seems to work with search field or filter, but it doesn't when I try to add it like that to 'fields'. Perhaps I do something wrong? How can I add that as a field? 
    fields = (
        'person_in_need__person_c__condition__issue',
    )
doesn't work

but 

    list_filter = (
        'person_in_need__person_c__condition__issue',
    )

does work

Comment: Yes, that's expected. If you wanted to put it into `fields` you'd have to make it readonly I think & potentially do it as a callable on the admin class. You certainly won't be able to do it as an editable field. It's likely most useful to you in `list_display`

Comment: I don't wanna edit it on the field, as I will create dictionary of pre-written issues and description. All I want to do on meeting view is to choose of pre-created issues for particular person. I will try to do it as readonly and list_display and will be back soon.

Comment: still doesn't seem to work, I am unsure why

Comment: @afdkj I've added an example of a callable to return related data.